# UK Visitor Visa - Genuine intention to visit

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I am in tier 2 general visa and I am planning to invite my in-laws from India to the UK in a standard visit visa. My Father in law is a farmer and he doesn't have bank statements to show as income proof or any financial status. We can show some agricultural lands registration documents which are actually not in English.

What kind of documents I can provide for him to prove **Genuine intention to visit**.

Comment: Even assuming he can get a certified translation of the land registration documents, this will likely be nigh on impossible without bank statements and documentation proving his income and ties to India. This guide contains information on what being a genuine visitor means and what ECOs look for https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF#page15

Comment: Why would your father in law return to India?